Else If statements unable to compile - "error: expected ';' before '{' token"
I am new. Please excuse me.
When compiling the following code that is entirely 'if' statements, the final "else" statement does not work. I receive the error message as mentioned in the title. If I change the final "else" to an "else if" the code will run. This makes no sense to me as I was told that the final statement should just be "else". Thanks for any help.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int menu, number1, number2;
  double sum;

  cout << "1: Addition\n2: Division\n\n";
  cin >> menu;

  if(menu == 1){    //Addition
    cout << "gimme a num: ";
    cin >> number1;
    cout << "gib another: ";
    cin >> number2;
    sum = number1 + number2;
    cout << sum;
  }else(menu == 2){     //division       !THIS IS THE LINE IN QUESTION!
    cout << "gimme a num: ";
    cin >> number1;
    cout << "gib another: ";
    cin >> number2;
    sum = number1 / number2;
    cout << sum;
  }

  return 0;
}



else(menu == 4) - what do you want to express here?

I am trying to get the block of code after the 'else' to run when menu = 4, but the code will not compile with an error on this line

if's have conditions; else's don't. If you need a test, you need an if, if all other options have been tested for and you don't need to check a condition, then you need neither an if or a condition check, but you could put in a comment for documentation purposes.

The answer below already solved your problem (don't forget to accept the answer), but I wanna add: the first 4 lines in each if block are the same, you could extract them and write them only once above. (maybe same for cout << sum, depending on error handling)

You could have removed 90% of that code and still shown the problem. And after you removed it you might have seen the problem yourself. Begin by simplifying; if that doesn't do it, post the simplified code.

You edited the code but you make the same mistake again. Either remove the (menu == 2) or change else into else if, depending upon what you want (is 3 and higher valid input or not)

@LexW. The edit preserves the question, Editing the question post to consist of corrected code would destroy it as a question and would need to be rolled back.

@Avi, I agree, but the edit as it is now more or less invalidates my answer and earlier comments too. The faulty condition is now menu == 2 instead of menu == 4.

@LexW. Agreed, the edit was not done by me. Although, it was done in good faith to address the excess fat I could have cut before posting my question

To test a different condition, you need an else if:
if (menu == 1) 
{
  // do stuff for 1
}
else if (menu == 2)
{
  // do stuff for 2
}
else
{
  // if neither 1 nor 2
}

In this particular case, you would be better served by using a switch case construct:
switch (menu)
{
  case 1:
    // do stuff for 1
    break;

  case 2:
    // do stuff for 2
    break;

  default:
    // if neither 1 nor 2
}

BTW, since it will matter as you move forward, it is a good idea to always get input from the user as a line of text and then parse it.
I have previously written up a bit of a “how to get user input” answer here that you may find useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78397016/2706707
You can use the methodology there to construct your menu:
switch (ask<int>( "1: addition\n2: division\n? " ))
{
  case ...

You can even put it all in a function:
enum OP { Addition = 1, Division };

OP menu()
{
  return ask<int>(
    "1: addition\n"
    "2: division\n"
    // other operations...?
    "? " );
}

int main()
{
  switch (menu())
  {
    case Addition:
      ...
      break;

    case Division:
      ...
      break;

    ...
  }

Notice the use of an enum to make reading (and maintaining) the code easier too.

Thank you for being constructive, this answer has helped me a lot.

Remove "(menu == 4)" after that last else.

Thank you! That was a dumb mistake on my part

No need to say thank you , instead please mark the answer as accepted.

If someone typed 5 this would still execute the last block. It depends on if you want that to happen or not.

This answer fixes the syntax error but is probably not the logic the OP wants in the event of invalid input, right?
